# Refactoring java in a single function that checks for null for different data types

Tags: java

I have a lot of statements like the following

```
boolean isIdEqual = (retrievedEdition.getId() == null && edition.getId() == null) || (retrievedEdition.getId() !=null && edition.getId() != null && retrievedEdition.getId().equals(edition.getId()));
```

that is used for unit testing. and I'm checking for null for several data types, like long, int, Integer, String.
I want a single function that can check for two data types and shorten the above statement and refactor that code.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` work out for you?

```
Objects.equals(retrievedEdition.getId(), edition.getId());
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-):

> Returns true if the arguments are equal to each other and false otherwise. Consequently, if both arguments are null, true is returned and if exactly one argument is null, false is returned. Otherwise, equality is determined by using the equals method of the first argument.

The `Objects` class was introduced in Java 7 and if you are using an earlier version the implementation looks like this:

```
/**
 * Returns {@code true} if the arguments are equal to each other
 * and {@code false} otherwise.
 * Consequently, if both arguments are {@code null}, {@code true}
 * is returned and if exactly one argument is {@code null}, {@code
 * false} is returned.  Otherwise, equality is determined by using
 * the {@link Object#equals equals} method of the first
 * argument.
 *
 * @param a an object
 * @param b an object to be compared with {@code a} for equality
 * @return {@code true} if the arguments are equal to each other
 * and {@code false} otherwise
 * @see Object#equals(Object)
 */
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Comment: I'm using a lower java version

Comment: @ahmedragia, I have added an implementation example for earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify that code using a ternary expression :

```
boolean isIdEqual = retrievedEdition.getId() != null ? retrievedEdition.getId().equals(edition.getId()) : edition.getId() == null;
```

Comment: how can I check a boolean for null then ?

Comment: @ahmedragia A boolean can't be null, since primitives can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things here..

**I'm checking for null for several data types, like long, int, Integer, String.** --> You can't check for `null` in case of *primitives*.

Next,

**I want a single function that can check for two data types**

Something like this might work..

```
boolean checkForNull(Object o1, Object o2){
 {
   //check here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Validator {
    public static boolean checkEqualsOrNull(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {  
            return false;
        } else {
           return o1.equals(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it as follow in your code

```
boolean isIdEqual = Validator.checkEqualsOrNull(retrievedEdition.getId() , 
                                                edition.getId());
```

This is a general purpose function that you can use for all your check.

Comment: what about a boolean ?

Comment: I get incompatible type with for return null for boolean

Comment: Sorry I changed it (return null -> return false) was a typing error. It is possible to call it also for boolean values for the autoboxing unboxing capabilities that converts the boolean to the equivalent Boolean wrapper.